# Adding ScrollView

Tags: java, android, eclipse, layout

I need a lot of text in my app, and so far, the text just stops at the bottom of my screen. It's not scrollable, so I need a scrollview on my page. Now I understood that it's just something like putting `Scrollview` in your `activity_main.xml`, but that hasn't worked out for me yet.

The text itself is put in my `strings.xml`, the textviews in my activity_mains.
This is the code for my `MainActivity`:

```
package com.example.rodekruis;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ContactActivity extends Activity {


     TextView HyperLink;
     Spanned Text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact);







    }




}
```

This is my activity_main code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.Bezoek" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rkz_logo"
        android:layout_marginLeft="38dp" />


     <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="276dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_contact"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />


</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is how it looks like in the Graphic Layout. The text stops halfway, i'm not able to scroll down.

[image]

Comment: Change Inner `LinearLayout` Height from Static to `Match_Parent`.

Comment: no, not match_parent but wrap_content ... and also TextView should have to have wrap_content as height... so @NicolasSimon is a right answer

Comment: it is showing as it should as you have given fix width and height. Keep it to `wrap_content`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change your layout as follow :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.Bezoek" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/rkz_logo"
    android:layout_marginLeft="38dp" />


  <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_width="244dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:text="@string/title_activity_contact"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
      android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Appreciate it a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the height of the `scrollview` to `wrap_content` like this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
```

Comment: seriously? `wrap_content` for `ScrollView's` height doesn't makes much sens ... in such case `ScrollView` takes a height from inner view and makes it unscrollable (because only something bigger in something smaller is scrollable)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Scroll View.

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this... you constraint the size at the scrollview instead of the textview.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="244dp"
    android:layout_height="276dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_contact"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

</ScrollView>
```